# Is this a decent method to display a currency number value without decimals?

Tags: php, math, currency

```
$value = '100.00';

echo $value * 100/100;
```

Or should I be rounding incase there's a value such as '100.70'? I'm displaying this for a table that displays daily rates, the total value contains the digits so I assume the user won't have to really worry about decimal values...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether or not you should round is up to you. But for this consider using [`sprintf()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).

```
$value = '100.00';
echo sprintf("%.0f', $value);
```

is *much* better than some arithmetic hack to achieve the same thing. Also, multiplying then dividing by 100 is like multiplying by 1.

Depending on what you want to achieve exactly, [`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) or even [`money_format()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) may be options as well.

To do the actual rounding use [`round()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php):

```
$value = '100.00';
echo round($value);
```

Comment: How would you do it personally?

Comment: I, personally, would round anything greater than .50 up to the next dollar.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $value * 100/100;
```

is equal to `$value * 1` kind sir

Use [number format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) to format your numbers instead of doing some fancy arithmetic

Answer (score 0):

Usually, people looking at columns of money want to see them all formatted the same way.  With different values, the second expression would `100.01  100.1  100` instead of `100.01  100.10  100.00`.

There are several ways to format numbers, including format_number, sprintf(), and simple string manipulation.